# Does AnyStock for AnyChart provide you with pattern recognition capabilities?

Tags: anychart, anychart-8.2

I noticed in the demo on the website it highlighted what looked like an ascending triangle pattern, does anystock provide pattern recognition for you?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no pattern recognition built-in. AnyChart Stock Chart Component supports building of several types of [annotations](https://docs.anychart.com/Stock_Charts/Drawing_Tools_and_Annotations/Overview) like [triangle](https://docs.anychart.com/Stock_Charts/Drawing_Tools_and_Annotations/Triangle), which can be added programmatically.